# How to create an Elastic plan from Azure Portal?

Tags: azure

I searched through Azure portal in Create a resource and didn't found this resource anywhere.
[image]

I was thinking that this resource was the same as the App Service Plan

[image]

But it doesn't have access to the same pricing tiers that the Elastic plan has.

Is there a way to create this resource without creating a Standard Logic App with it?

Comment: [Get started with Elastic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/partner-solutions/elastic/create) and [How to deploy and manage Elastic on Microsoft Azure](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-the-azure-integration-enhancement)

Comment: Hi @DeepDave-MT, are we talking about the same thing? I don't want to create an ElasticSearch resource. What i want is to create that Elastic Plan resource (which is a bit different that the App Service Plan)